# Correct naming convention for Cloud Run: gcloud builds submit media bucket names (The specified bucket does not exist)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/run) to upload my existing Django project running locally to Google Cloud Run. I believe I have followed all the steps correctly to create the bucket and grant it the necessary permissions. But when I try to run:

```sh
gcloud builds submit \
--config cloudmigrate.yaml \
--substitutions=_INSTANCE_NAME=cgps-reg-2-postgre-sql,_REGION=us-central1
```

I get the error:

```
Step #3 - "collect static": google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/cgps-registration-2_cgps-reg-2-static-files-bucket/o?uploadType=multipart&predefinedAcl=publicRead:
```

[image]

I was a little confused by [this line](https://cln.sh/K9yP4o) that seams to tell you to put the bucket name in the location field, but I think its perhaps just a typo in the tutorial. I was not sure if I should leave location at the default "Multi-Region" or change it to "us-central1" where everyting else in the project is.

The instructions for telling the project the name of the bucket I interpreted as `PROJECT_ID + "_" + BUCKET_NAME`:

[image: echo GS_BUCKET_NAME=PROJECT_ID_MEDIA_BUCKET >> .env]

or in my case

```
cgps-registration-2_cgps-reg-2-static-files-bucket
```

[image]

But clearly this naming convention is not correct as the error clearly says it can not find a bucket with this name. So what am I missing here?

Comment: Your bucket name is `cgps-reg-2-static-files-bucket`. This is its globally unique name. You should not prefix it (again) with the Project name when referencing it. The error is telling you (correctly) that the bucket (called `cgps-registration-2_cgps-reg-2-static-files-bucket`) does not exist. It does not. The bucket is called `cgps-reg-2-static-files-bucket`

Comment: Because bucket names must be unique, one way to create them it to combine another unique name i.e. the Google Cloud Project ID in their naming. The tutorial likely confused you by using this approach but without explaining it.

Comment: Only to complement @dazwilkin’s comment, I do agree the Google tutorial you followed could be indeed confusing.
I suggest you to follow this Django on Cloud Run codelab tutorial to dispel that confusion: https://kiosk-dot-codelabs-site.appspot.com/codelabs/cloud-run-django/index.html?index=..%2F..index#1, to be more specific, please focus on activity 5. This codelab tutorial could also be helpful in case you want to continue working with future Django Projects.

Answer (score 1):

Credit for this answer really goes to dazwilken. The answer he gave in the comment is the correct one:

> Your bucket name is `cgps-reg-2-static-files-bucket`. This is its
> globally unique name. You should not prefix it (again) with the
> Project name when referencing it. The error is telling you (correctly)
> that the bucket (called
> `cgps-registration-2_cgps-reg-2-static-files-bucket`) does not exist. It
> does not. The bucket is called `cgps-reg-2-static-files-bucket`
>
> Because bucket names must be unique, one way to create them it to
> combine another unique name i.e. the Google Cloud Project ID in their
> naming. The tutorial likely confused you by using this approach but
> without explaining it.

Comment: I would suggest you to consider your answer as a community wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki, here is more documentation in stackexchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts.

Community Wiki posts function by passing part of the author's ownership of the post to the community. They make it easier for a larger number of users to update and maintain the post, but they have no bearing on any user's reputation.